# Putting data in a php file

Tags: php

I am new to coding with PHP and I've got a problem. What I want to do is simple.

`updateable1`, `updateable2` and `updateable3` are empty in the beginning. Then I'm calling the `modifydata` function to put data into these variables. After that I want to get the data from another place so I'm calling to get the data (for example updateable2) but I'm getting nothing aka "". That means that when I did the call to `modifydata` it didn't do anything or the file didn't save.

If there is someone who can help me that would be very cool.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
global $updateable1;
global $updateable2;
global $updateable3;
$updateable1 = "";
$updateable2 = "";
$updateable3 = "";

function modifyData() {
    include("mta_sdk.php");
    $input = mta::getInput();
    global $updateable1, $updateable2, $updateable3;
    $updateable1 = $input[0];
    $updateable2 = $input[1];
    $updateable3 = $input[2];
    mta::doReturn($updateable2);
}

if (isset($_GET['vdt']) && $_GET['vdt'] == '1') {
    global $updateable2;
    echo $updateable2;
} elseif (isset($_GET['mvp']) && $_GET['mvp'] == '1') {
    global $updateable3;
    echo $updateable3;
} elseif (isset($_GET['update']) && $_GET['update'] == '1') {
    modifyData();
} else {
    global $updateable1;
    echo $updateable1;
}
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Are you certain `$input` is being populated correctly? Is the `modifyData()` function  definitely being executed (`$_GET['update'] == 1`)? Your provided example leaves too many unknowns. FYI, you don't need to use the `global` keyword outside of functions as they are already globally scoped but you are using it correctly inside the function.